# known_hosts file on HCI giving Error: HostKey has been changed

Tags: foreign-keys, integration, hana, sap-business-technology-platform

I'm trying to add the ***`known_hosts`*** file on HCI. I added the RSS public key on SSH server and added that public key in `known_hosts` file with ***`host_name ssh-rsa`*** in prefix with RSA public key. Hence the output is like: ***`host_name ssh-rsa AAAAB...`***

When I uploaded the key on HCI then I got an error

> Message processing failed
>
> Processing Time: 9 sec 673 ms
>
> Error Details
>
> org.apache.camel. component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot connect to sftp://xxxxT@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com:22, cause: com.jcraft.jsch.jSchException: HostKey has been changed: xxxxxxxxxxxx.com

[image: Host Key error]

Till now, my SFTP is enabled with its public key and now trying to upload `known.hosts` file on HCI, and I'm not sure where to upload the private key of SFTP. I'm having 3 files:

- `privateKey_SFTP.ppk`
- `publicKey_SFTP.pub`
- `publicKey_SSH.pub`

[image: Keys for SFTP]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create keys via SAP, nothing else will work https://blogs.sap.com/2016/07/10/sftp-connectivity-using-hcihcp-integration-services/
https://blogs.sap.com/2017/08/03/cloud-integration-how-to-setup-secure-connection-to-sftp-server/